# How to rename files in a directory using bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to find a bash script for renaming files with _ (underscore) to - (hyphen)

for example changing file name my_page_name.php to my-page-name.php,
keeping the name of the file of those without .php extension same

I attempted:
Nothing yet , just used the script found here bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=36305 and replace space with _ and underscore with -

Comment: Nothing yet , just used the script found here
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=36305
and replace space with _ and underscore with -

Comment: Instead of mentioning the link in the comment, update the post with your attempts so far.

Comment: Don't post the link to the script in your post; instead post the script you used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to do it in one directory (and not subdirectories):

```
for f in *_*; do mv "$f" "${f//_/-}"; done
```

Otherwise, you can use `find` to `-exec` a bash subshell.

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables, you never know if a file with whitespace in its name slips in.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Fair enough. It's more general that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rename` program:

```
rename s:_:-: *.php
```